# Cannot set SelectedIndex to 0

Tags: c#, wpf

When trying to set a ComboBox SelectedIndex to 0 so I have the first value as default, doesn't work, the combobox its empty by default. If I try setting it to any other number it works, I have the selected index as a default value.

Anyone have an idea why I can't set it to 0 from xaml ?

```
<RSControls:SmoothScrollComboBox
    Grid.Column="1"
    x:Name="comboTypes"
    Margin="7,0,0,0"
    SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SelectedTypes}"
    SelectedValuePath="Name"
    SelectedIndex="0"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource GroupedTypes}}"
    DisplayMemberPath="Display"
    SelectionChanged="comboTypes_SelectionChanged"
    IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
```

PS: forgot to mention that I have 2 comboboxes, the other one works, implemented in the same way, only the Selectedvalue and ItemSource differs.

Comment: You're mixing a lot of `SelectedFoo` together at one time.

Comment: I have another combobox that works well, implemented this way, but for this one, it does not, could this be a problem, because I have two comboboxes ?

Comment: Are you binding at all? Maybe the SelectedItem is being set externally overriding your SelectedIndex

Comment: Its not set externally, only for 0 it doesnt work, if I set it to any other number all is well, the item at the selectedindex is set as default when loading the project

Comment: OK, i solved the problem by replacing SelectedValue with SelectedIndex="0". I apreciate if someone could provide this as an answer so i can accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably because you are setting the selected item twice: once with `SelectedIndex` and once with `SelectedValue`

Remove the `SelectedValue` property and `SelectedIndex` should work